# Add Method to Class Using Swig

Tags: c++, python, swig

I'm in the process of wrapping a class in C++ that is to be subclassed in Python. To test that this works correctly, I wanted to use the %extend swig option to add a test method to be called from Python. Even with the use of a very simple C++ class that I threw together, any attempt to add a method resulted in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    a.p()
  File "Monkey.py", line 87, in p
    def p(self): return _Monkey.Bar_p(self)
TypeError: in method 'Bar_p', argument 1 of type 'Bar *'`
```

How do I add methods to a C++ class with swig?

Example of code that was used:

## Foo.h

```
class Bar
{
    public:
        Bar();
        virtual ~Bar();
        virtual void car() = 0;
};
```

## Foo.i

```
%module(directors="1") Monkey
%{
#include <iostream>
#include "Foo.h"
%}

%include "Foo.h"

%feature("director") Bar::car;

%extend Bar
{
    void p()
    {
        std::cout<<"p";
    }
};
```

Comment: There seems to be some code missing here because from what you've shown you can't instantiate `Bar`. What's in your test.py file?